# Where Azure SQL Database logs for failed Data Manipulation SQL queries?

Tags: sql, azure, debugging, logging, azure-sql-database

I can find [tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/sql-insights-overview) in Azure to monitor and get logs on the performance of the Azure SQL database. However, what tools are available in the Azure portal to see logs of failed SQL data manipulation queries of the database? - e.g. update, delete, insert queries?

Thank you

Comment: Did you mean that you wanna a tool to show all the logs of sql executing result, especially those are failed to execute? E.g your app may execute 1000 times of sql querying, and you wanna know when and which query failed? If so, I think azure application insights can provide such feature.https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktaaN.png

Comment: Hey @TinyWang, the Azure DB or server don't give me an option to add Application Insights (unlike e.g. a function app which is what your screenshot looks like?) -, where do you add Application Insights for a DB?

Comment: I added application insights sdk to the program which connect to the database, per my understanding,database exists for programming using.... And it seems that you just wanna log those crud commands executed in database protal.

Comment: thanks @TinyWang yes I wanted to get deeper into the logs of the DB, not only what AI provides from a program that works with the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone need this to I got an answer elsewhere with Extended Events though didn't yet try https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/extended-events-capture-step-by-step-walkthrough/ba-p/369013